# javascript replace regex not global

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
//Get width and resize another element
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ResizeSearch(GridID, SearchID) {
    var eleWidth = $("#" + GridID).width();
    $("#" + SearchID).width(eleWidth);
  }
  $("#getp").click(function() {
    ResizeSearch("<%= gvValidStatus.ClientID %>", "ValidStatusSearch");
  });
});
```

This is a simple question for a lot of you stackoverflow people. I've got a little bit of code that looks like this:

```
var www = '?points=City%20Chairman%20Brutas&another=test';
var name = 'points';
var match = RegExp(RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(www)[1]);
match = decodeURIComponent(match); 
match = match.replace('\/','');
document.write(match);
```

The code is pretty straight forward, for jsfiddle purposes I made a `var` instead of using `window.location.search`. I understand that I NEED to make `match.replace` GLOBAL for this to work correctly. It currently outputs this:

```
City Chairman Brutas/
```

If I change `match.replace` to `match.replace('\//g','');` it doesn't work.

Output of above: `/City Chairman Brutas/`

I know I'm close, if anybody could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes and use the `/.../` regex literal syntax instead:

```
match.replace(/\//g,'');
```

Comment: Thanks, I always thought the regex had to be in between ''

Comment: When using a string it's treated as plain text. The only way to use a string as a regex is passing it to the `'RegExp()` constructor. And in this case you do not include any delimiters and pass the flags as a second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
match = match.replace(/\//g,'');
```

Should work. You need a regex-delimiter / at the start and the end of your regex. Your flags then come after the end-delimiter.
Also, as pointed out below, you should not put quotes around your regex..!

Comment: When passing a string to `replace()` it's not a regex but a plain string. What you probably wanted was `.replace(/\//g, '')`

Comment: I must admit I've been using PHP lately... Edited and upvoted your answer ;-)